# Can I use memchr safely with an internal UTF-8 char * returned from an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, strlen

I'd like to use `memchr` instead of `strlen` to find the length of a C string potentially used as the backing string of an NSString. Is this safe to do, or do I risk reading memory that I don't own, causing a crash? Let's assume that the NSString will not be released before I'm done with the internal buffer.

Comment: I see no reason why it may be unsafe as long as the pointer remains valid. But the hard question is that you can't easily tell when the pointer is freed unless you just get it from `NSString`, then you should just call `length` on it

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473872/lifespan-of-nsstring-cstringusingencoding-return-value.

Comment: Why aren't you calling `-length` on the string directly?

Answer (score 1):

`memchr(s, 0, XXX)` and `strlen(s)` should pretty much behave identically, save for `mechr()`'s ability to terminate after XXX bytes.   But `strnlen()` can do that, too.

And that behavior is probably exactly what you *don't* want.

Neither function accounts for any kind of unicode encoding.  Thus, the returned length will be the length-in-bytes and not the # of characters.

Use `-length` on the `NSString` if you want the string length.   Beyond that, what are you trying to do?

Comment: This is just for a UTF-8 string. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @meisel `strlen()` will give you the byte length, not the character length.  So will `memchr()`.  So, again, very unlikely that this is really what you want.  If you want to treat the string as a generic buffer of bytes convert it to an `NSData` or copy the bytes out into a separate buffer in isolation from the string.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I want. I eventually, this string will be part of a larger string that is then used to create an NSString. My strategy is, take buffers out of Objective-C objects, do processing on them, recombine as an NSString for users of the API. It's very fast and doesn't need to think about how UTF-8 works, except that it's null-terminated.

Comment: @meisel Sounds like what you _really_ want to be doing is accessing this via `NSMutableData` as a bag of bytes, perform the modifications that you want, then create real strings out of that...

Comment: I'd *highly* recommend you pull the data out in the encoding you need, process it as you see fit, and then put it into a new `NSString`.    I also suspect that the *I don't need to think about how UTF-8 works* will come back to haunt you, but at least if you control the encoding in/out, you'll have a known quantity.

Comment: @bbum my main concern is that I'll be accessing memory that I don't own. If you can address that, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @meisel If you call `-UTF8String`, the returned buffer is owned by the string.  As long as the string isn't deallocated (or mutated, in case of mutable string), then that buffer pointer will remain valid.   If the string's lifespan is unknown, then you either need to hold a hard reference to it or use one of the `getBytes....` variants to copy the data.

Comment: @bbum the problem with a function like this is that it could be vectorized, so it may try to access memory past the end of the string. The question is, are there always at least, say, 32 bytes that we own after the end of the string? E.g., maybe NSString has 4+ ivars after the UTF8String pointer.

Comment: @meisel There is no way to know or guarantee any such allocation exists unless you also allocate the backing store for the `NSString` (which you can do).   If you have strict buffer requirements of that nature, you're going to have to either copy the contents of the string or control the creation in the first place.

Comment: @bbum how can you be so sure? Maybe the way things are laid out, we always have 32+ bytes after the end of any object, e.g. an NSString

Comment: @meisel I can be **absolutely sure** that there is no guarantee that such a layout will always be present because (a) there is no documented claim in the API that said behavior exists and (b) because I have the source.

Comment: @bbum can you link the source?

Comment: @meisel Much of NSString is implemented in CoreFoundation, but not all.  I believe that is on the Apple open source site.  For the rest, you'd need to join Apple (as I did 13 years ago).

But, again, I can guarantee that there isn't a 32 byte pad on these buffers;  it'd waste too much memory. Especially with constant strings (NSCFConstantString).  For non-constant strings, the buffers are *typically* going to be padded to malloc-good-size.  For a subset of strings, there'll be no buffer at all because they are implemented as *tagged pointers*.

Comment: My point is not that there's a 32-byte pad on the buffers, it's that the way the memory may be laid out, the objects may always have more than 32 bytes in between them and the end of the memory that my app owns. It just depends how Apple does things.

Comment: @meisel Again, **unless the API contract explicitly makes such a claim**, you cannot rely on it, *even if you have the source* (because it might change from release to release).  And, furthermore, I can-- you can, with a very simple bit of code-- guarantee that it is not always the case.